# Update data in Table View after user received push notification

Tags: swift, push-notification, realm

I have an app with push notifications and RealmDB. User himself chooses the date of notifications after that the notification date goes to the RealmDB. Every time a user receives a notification, the date of the next notification changes, and the user can see the date in Table View. Problem is...after the user has received the notification, he goes to the application through the push notification so func doesn't work. If user go to app by open it - everything is OK.
In cellForRowAt:

```
center.getDeliveredNotifications { (notifications) in
        for notification:UNNotification in notifications {
            print(notification.request.identifier)
            if (notification.request.identifier == timeId){
                
                let today = notification.date
                
                let realNextDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: timeInterval!, to: today)
                
                let realm = try! Realm()
            
                try! realm.write {
                    for plants in realm.objects(MyPlant.self).filter("id == %@", timeId as Any) {
                        plants.nextDate = realNextDate
                        plants.prevDate = today
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will guess that `timeId` is undefined or not what is expected so the filter doesn't return an object to update. However, that code was not included so it's a wild guess. Also, why a for-loop when you want a single object as defined by it's id?

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this I believe is that you are configuring `Realm` in the `AppDelegate` with

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

This is what is executed when you open the app by tapping on the `App icon`. In the case where you open the app by tapping the `push notification`, the above `AppDelegate` method isn't executed. Instead a method shown below is executed,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    // unused
}
```

Due to this, you will have to do some configurations in this method as well for it to work when tapped on the notification.

Comment: This answer *could* be 100% right but how in the world do you know they have anything like `RealmService.shared.config()`? I ask because the code in the question doesn't use a RealmService because they are using `let realm = try! Realm()` every time it's called. Just curious.

Comment: My bad, It was a service I had made for my apps, copy pasted haha. Let me fix it real quick

Comment: lol. Cool. Keep in mind that for local only realms using the `default.realm` file, no configuration is necessary - all that's needed is `let realm = try! Realm()` and it will work every time. Since that statement is being used in the code in the question - it's the assumption their using the default. But who knows, question is vague.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and i am so sorry, but its not your service copy pasted:)